# AppleCare Status On My Mac: Ways to Check?

Tags: applecare

I am aware that one can check the AppleCare Status of their Mac by going to [Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/).

What other ways exist (that maybe inbuilt within OS X) to clarify this, and possibly even schedule a repair ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Mountain Lion, it's possible to check from the machine itself. From the Apple Menu, select `About this Mac`, then `More Info...`. On the next screen, select `Service` and then `Check my service and support coverage status` and you should find all the information you need.

The above was taken from [The Mac Observer](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/incredibly-easy-fast-way-to-check-applecare-status-of-your-mac)

Comment: This also works in Lion.